# No value retrieved from dropdown list with python mechanize when scraping a dynamic webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm completely new to web scraping. I'm trying to follow the code snippet found in this question [Web Scraper for dynamic forms in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607410/web-scraper-for-dynamic-forms-in-python/30609130#30609130)

I'm doing similar search with http://www.goodlifefitness.com/fitness-classes/find-a-class/. Filling in Province, City and Class Name, and search for schedule.

But I'm stuck with step one, retrieving a list of Provinces

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                

import re
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('http://www.goodlifefitness.com/fitness-classes/find-a-class/')

br.select_form('aspnetForm')
ctl = br.form.find_control('ctl00$Copy$ddlRegion')
```

But it seems that I cannot even get anything from the dropdown list

```
>>> items=ctl.get_items()
>>> items
[<Item name='' id=None selected='selected' contents='' value='' label=''>]
```

But when I inspect the element on the webpage, clearly there are values in the first dropdown list

```
<select name="ctl00$Copy$ddlRegion" id="ctl00_Copy_ddlRegion" title="Select a Province" class="dropdown" onchange="comboBoxSearch_onChange(this);">

<option value="">Select a Province</option><option value="Alberta">Alberta</option><option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option><option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option><option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option><option value="Newfoundland">Newfoundland</option><option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option><option value="Ontario">Ontario</option><option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option></select>
```

Why `ctl.get_items()` returned nothing?
Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see if you do View Source in Firefox, the items you're looking for aren't in the original HTML markup sent by the server. In fact, they are added by a JavaScript after the page has loaded. Mechanize doesn't run JavaScript, so it can't see those items; it only sees what's in the HTML.

As an aside, this completely unnecessary use of JavaScript is a plague on modern Web development and makes doing things like you're trying to do much harder than they should be. (But then, maybe that's why they do it.)

Anyway, to scrape that information from the page, you need to use something that actually loads the page in a real Web browser, such as Selenium.

The other SO question you linked is different because the targeted site actually sends an HTTP POST when you select from the menus, and receives a whole new HTTP page back. This page doesn't do that.