# Python Web scraper for dynamically populating drop down list (using mechanize and beautifulsoup(

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize-python

i am newbie to python. I am using python 2.7 and trying to scrape the website and collect the data . I am having issue in selection of drop down list and getting new response form with updated list of items.

These are the steps :

1. I am opening a xyz.com website
2. Its UI appears as in the attached image link
3. There are 5 drop down menus displayed in the initial form we open. They are : 
   State
   District
   Sub District
   Village
   Year Cycle

And only State and Year cycle are initially populated. And rest of the drop down menus are dependent on one another in a sequential order. Eg : 
When state is selected --> It populates District in a dynamic manner. And when District is selected --> It populates Sub District and similarly Village is populated with the selection of Sub district. And this dynamic update is happening because of javascript.

So far am able to get to the stage of collecting list of states (Used beautifulsoup and mechanize). And initially am just choosing one state and submitting the form as :

```
def select_form(form):
   return form.attrs.get('action', None) == '/PublicReports/NutrientStatusFarmerWise'


br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)
br.response()
br.select_form(predicate=select_form)
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
br.form['State_Code'] = ['29']  
response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```

And when i print the response.read i dont see newly populated district names. I dont know what am missing here. As in the similar manner, i need to collect district names to populate subdistrict and so on with the rest of items.

Any clues and hints would be of great help

PS :  I have read the old post and used it as reference :
[Web Scraper for dynamic forms in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607410/web-scraper-for-dynamic-forms-in-python)

[form with drop down options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mqnp.jpg)

Thank you !

Comment: I have a feeling you're going to need to use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: I dont want to use selenium .. this is not for testing purpose

Comment: What do you mean "this is not for testing purpose"?

Comment: I mean for this web scraping i just want to use command line utilities and not any testing tools like selenium

Comment: Selenium can be used to "click" the drop downs for you and then retrieve the data you need. Web-scraping, especially on sites that are "onto web-scrapers" and make it difficult on purpose, may not be as easy as a few lines of code.